# Should "strong-ai" and "agi" be synonymous?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

Some people say that strong AI would be an AGI with consciousness/self-awareness (see e.g. the Chinese Room argument), but that, in general, an AGI may not be conscious (whatever the definition of consciousness or self-awareness is), so AGI and strong AI are not necessarily synonymous. Of course, this is arguable and debatable: in other words, can we really build an AGI that is not conscious? This is a philosophical question, which I don't really want to further discuss here.

My question is about tags.

Should "strong-ai" and "agi" be synonymyms, if the only difference between the two is that that strong AI is an AGI with consciousness?  Note that this may not always be the definition that is used when people use the term "strong AI": they may just be referring to AGI. In fact, [Ben Goertzel writes](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Artificial_General_Intelligence)

> A dichotomy has sometimes been drawn between AGI and "narrow AI" (Goertzel and Pennachin, 2005). For example, Kurzweil (1999) contrasted "narrow AI" with "strong AI" -- using the former to refer to the creation of systems that carry out specific "intelligent" behaviors in specific contexts, and the latter to refer essentially to what is now called AGI.

A few months ago, I decided to merge the two tags (because the difference may not even exist), but now that I think about it, maybe I should have asked the community first.

In any case, I think we should still have them merged, as it is now.